# types which behave like sets

Tags: set-theory, type-theory, homotopy-type-theory

I'm reading the homotopy type theory book and this sentence is giving me trouble.
"We can define a class of types which behave like sets. Homotopically, these can be thought of as spaces in which every connected component is contractible, i.e. those which are homotopy equivalent to a discrete space."

I am struggling to see the connections between these concepts. In what respect does a class of types where each connected component is contractable necessarily behave like a set?

Thank you.

Comment: My hunch on it that *sets* in HoTT and sets usually mentioned by set theorists are not the same concept. They are the same only in the sense that both of them are *discrete*. You may refer to structural set theories like ETCS to see what type-theoretic sets look like.

Comment: yes! after reading your comment, i took a look at this http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/reprints/articles/11/tr11.pdf and just the first two pages cleared up a lot for me. the intuitive notions discussed there lend themselves well to formalization with "every connected component is contractible". thank you!

Comment: I think the HoTT book is saying that if you restrict to types $A$ such that for all $a\colon A$ the type $a=_Aa$ has only the element $\mathrm{Id}_a$, then you get things that beheave like sets, they have no nontrivial higher homotopy informations. It's been a lot of time since I thought about ant HoTT though so I might be very wrong

Comment: That's right.  *Each* type with contractible components (not the class of such types) behaves like a set in the "strurctural" ETCs sense.